# strange ejs syntax error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am new to `node.js`  and follow a blog to practice.But when i come to render a view as written in blog. I met some strange problems.

I take `ejs` as view engine in `express` and `signup.ejs` like this

```
<%- include('header') %>
  <div class="ui grid">
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="eight wide column">
   <form class="ui form segment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field required">
      <label>username</label>
      <input placeholder="username" type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="field required">
      <label>password</label>
      <input placeholder="password" type="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="field required">
      <label>repeat password</label>
      <input placeholder="password" type="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="field required">
      <label>sex</label>
      <select class="ui compact selection dropdown" name="gender">
        <option>m</option>
        <option>f</option>
        <option>x</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="field required">
      <label>avatar</label>
      <input type="file" name="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="field required">
      <label>bio</label>
      <textarea name="bio" rows="5" v-model="user.bio"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

when i run start my program and send a http request in path`localhost:3000/signup`,I get some mistakes

```
SyntaxError: 
C:\Users\ct\Documents\mycode\nodestudy\formalblog\views\signup.ejs:1
 >> 1| <%- include('header') %>
    2| <div class="ui grid">
    3|   <div class="four wide column"></div>
    4|   <div class="eight wide column">

C:\Users\ct\Documents\mycode\nodestudy\formalblog\views\header.ejs:13
    11|   <body>
    12|     <%- include('components/nav') %>
 >> 13|     <%- include('components/nav-setting') %>
    14|     <%- include('components/notification') %>
Unexpected token if in         C:\Users\ct\Documents\mycode\nodestudy\formalblog\views\components\nav-setting.ejs while compiling ejs
```

I have checked the file path and my `node version is v7.2.0 for win` and `ejs version 2.5.6`. I have read the docs for ejs but i have no idea about the mistake info `syntax error`.

update:  show content in `nav-setting.ejs`,thanks for remind me where mistake truely happen.

```
<div class="nav-setting">
  <div class="ui buttons">
    <div class="ui floating dropdown button">
      <i class="icon bars"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <%= if (user) { %>
        <a class="item" href="/posts?author=<%= user._id %>">index</a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
         <a class="item" href="/posts/create">post</div>
         <a class="item" href="/signout">logout</a>
      <% } else { %>
         <a class="item" href="/signin">login</a>
         <a class="item" href="/signup">signup</a>
      <% } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the tools your error is actually in `nav-settings.ejs` file. The rest is just to point out why the other files fail to compile (because they use that `nav-settings.ejs` file directly or indirectly).

Comment: Show contents of `nav-setting.ejs` (in folder C:\Users\ct\Documents\mycode\nodestudy\formalblog\views\components\ )

Comment: I have added the content in `nav-setting.ejs` ,thanks for your comment.

Comment: Let me guess, `<%= ... >` expects an expression to interpolate into the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys who leave a comment on this simple question.

As @user268396 and  @Sangharsh said , mistake happens in `nav-setting.ejs` but not in `signup.ejs`. After i checked `nav-setting.ejs`, I found that `<%= if(user) {%>` is wrong syntax in ejs. `<% if(user) { %>`  should be used here .

`<% %>` and `<%= %>` are both used to control document but <% %> won't produce an output, so it should be the correct choice.

Thanks again  for your answer.

Comment: `<%= %>` || `<%- %>` will expect a value to be produced, but `<% %>` are used for the expression